# Issue with spring auto wiring with abstract class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have below **abstract** class.

### Sender.java

```
public abstract class Sender{

 public abstract void send(String id);
}
```

### AttachSender.java

```
@Service("attachSender")
public class AttachSender extends Sender{

//It implements send() method here


}
```

### SomeOtherClass.java

```
public class SomeOtherClass implements SomeOther{

@Autowired
private AttachSender attachSender;


}
```

Here i have an issue and the above code is not working.
My question is can i autowire the class instead of interface as above?
In my case **AttachSender**  is a class but not interface.,

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean _is not working_? What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you have issues they should be elsewhere.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683408/autowiring-spring-superclass) deals with wiring a superclass, which might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

`@service` annotation looks wrong.

should be `@Service`

Comment: yes, but if that were the problem, code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Then post details of the error. It's probably not being scanned.

Comment: My super class is abstract class. will be there be any issues?

Comment: Not if you're injecting a subtype no.